Sur la nature du suffixe « -os », terme pour les suffixes qui ne changent pas le sens
Le suffixe de récente origine (populaire), « -os », entre dans la morphologie des mots selon trois formats : il sert à former des adj. à partir d'adj., des adv. à partir d'adv. et des noms à partir de noms.

(TLFi)
A. − [Finale d'adj. inv.; la base est un adj.] :
chicos. Chic.
chouettos. Chouette
débilos. Débile.
minablos. Minable.
rouquinos. Rouquin, rouquine.
rupinos. Rupin, rupine.
sinistros. Sinistre.
tristos. Triste.
B. − [Suff. formateur d'adv.; la base est un adj.] :
rapidos. Rapidement.
C. − [Suff. formateur de subst.; la base est un
subst. parfois tronqué] :
béguinos, subst. masc.Béguin
burinos, subst. masc.Burin.
matos, subst. masc. Matériel (de musique).

Alors que tous les suffixes servent à changer le sens ou à le modifier légèrement (cloche/clochette, riche/richard) celui-ci  a la particularité de ne pas changer le sens du mot auquel il est affixé—ce qui lui donne une apparente qualité de superflu—, sauf dans un seul des cas proposés dans le TLFi (voir « matos » ci-dessus et dans le TLFi (Depuis la parution du TLFi le sens a changé (matos)).
Est-on au courant d'un nom pour cette sorte de suffixe? (I semble que ce soit le seul des suffixes de la langue française qui ait cette propriété , mais il en  existe peut-être d'autres dans  la langue populaire, de nature encore plus marginale ((Liste des suffixes de la langue française), « -os » manque), qui ont la même propriété, ce qui aurait pu justifié un terme dans les recherches de quelque spécialiste.)

Pas sûr du tout que le suffixe n'ait aucun sens, il rend en général la base plus péjorative et plus vulgaire que sa racine.

@Eauquidort Il n'a pas de sens défini lexicalement, et dans la langue des jeunes, les jeunes eux-mêmes ne lui en reconnaissent pas (c'est une mode, ou plutôt, c'était une mode) : https://www.persee.fr/doc/lfr_0023-8368_1997_num_114_1_5382. Je suis cependant d'accord sur le fait que certaines connotations sont perceptibles, et semble imprécises, parfois présentes, parfois absentes.

Selon plusieurs sources, la suffixation en "-os" aurait pour rôle majeur une désignation argotique des termes de la langue française. Plusieurs sources désigneraient son origine comme latine ou espagnole. On lui trouve différentes dénominations : déformateur d'adjectif, d'adverbe, de nom ou de verbe selon qu'il soit respectivement un suffixe adjectival, adverbal, nominal ou verbal. Un auteur désigne également une "suffixation parasitaire", mais je recommande la lecture de ce document pour plus de détails et de contexte, où ledit auteur propose également l'utilisation de la particule comme d'un moyen d'accentuer le sens d'un mot. Enfin, on trouvera moult exemples d'utilisation du suffixe "-os" sur Wikipedia et ses sources.

« Suffixation parasitaire » est un terme à garder à l'esprit en rapport aux suffixes en général, mais il ne caractérise pas le fait de ne communiquer aucun sens bien défini. Il n'y aurait peut-être pas d'autre suffixes de cette sorte. // L'article est très utile mais je crois que l'auteur néglige un aspect : c'est l'aspect argotique que l'on trouve dans le roman noir (type « San Antonio ») ; il s'en tient à la langue des jeunes (qui  a déjà décrété que ce suffixe était démodé).

@LPH cependant il cite l'exemple des cigarillos en espagnol, qui seraient des petits "cigares vulgaires". Je pense également aux suffixes "-asse" et "-ard" également (souvent) utilisés dans un objectif de rendre un terme péjoratif voire insultant, sans pour autant faire perdre au mot initial sons sens propre.
